# How can I implement an atomic concurrent read of a document in RavenDB?

Tags: rest, concurrency, thread-safety, queue, ravendb

I have the following problem, I am implementing a queue abstraction with RavenDB in a stateless REST server.

Suppose I have 2 REST calls A and B

When call A is happening I query the queue for the last item ( item A ) and give it to call A.

If call B is called at the same time as call A - which can happen with REST calls, I need to prevent the program from giving call B the same item as A meaning item A should be "locked" by the call A.

A standard multi-threaded protection here would be a simple lock, how do I translate this idea to my situation with RavenDB and REST?

P.S I use [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) for the REST server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should not be too hard unless I missed something:

Introduce a flag (boolean property) on your items, e.g. "Processed".
Inside your action, open up a new RavenDB session and enable optimistic concurrency on it (`DocumentSession.Advanced .UseOptimisticConcurrency`).
Get the next unprocessed item and then immediately update its processed flag to true.
Call `.SaveChanges` on your session -> if that succeeds (you don't get a `ConcurrencyException`), you can safely return the item as the result of the request. If not, load the next item.

Comment: Can there be a situation where both calls update exactly at the same time and exception isn't thrown? I guess it depends on how it is implemented inside RavenDB

Comment: No, that's impossible. All changes on your documents between calls to `SaveChanges`are fully transactional, that means either all or none succeed. Enabling OptimisticConcurrency on your Session it is guaranteed that no one else has modified the document before. (btw: RavenDB even has support for System.Transaction, so that you can span longer transactions, but that makes no sense in your case, just as info).

Comment: @DanielLang Hi Daniel, your answer is very helpful. Just want to ask, by using UseOptimisticConcurrency on a single field like 'Processed', can it guarantee the atomicity across many clients visiting a cluster of RavenDBs (in a distributed environment)? Or do I need an explicit 'transaction'? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dodd, what do you mean by a 'cluster'? You can either have replicated instances in which you most probably have a master/slave setup with read-only (or alternatively read/write) failover or sharded instances. No need for transactions, the same logic applies.